# Spring WebFlow - problem with rest mapping

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I have problem with mapping in Spring Webflow 2.3.0

I got error when I want to excute:

http://localhost:8090/myWebApp/**register/other**

http://localhost:8090/myWebApp/verify or 
http://localhost:8090/myWebApp/register etc works

Can anybody help?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order">
            <value>1</value>
        </property>
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>
                /register=flowController
                /verify=flowController
                /forgotPassword=flowController 
                /register/other=flowController     
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
    </bean>

...

<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry"
        flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
        <webflow:flow-location id="verify" path="/WEB-INF/flows/verify.xml"></webflow:flow-location>
        <webflow:flow-location id="register" path="/WEB-INF/flows/register.xml"></webflow:flow-location>
        <webflow:flow-location id="changeLang" path="/WEB-INF/flows/changeLang.xml"></webflow:flow-location>
        <webflow:flow-location id="forgotPassword" path="/WEB-INF/flows/forgotPassword.xml"></webflow:flow-location>
        <webflow:flow-location id="register/other" path="/WEB-INF/flows/other.xml"></webflow:flow-location>
    </webflow:flow-registry>
```

I got error in runtime:

http://localhost:8090/myWebApp/register/other

org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.NoSuchFlowDefinitionException: No flow definition 'other' found

Answer (score 2):

Webflow is not restful - what you're looking for is impossible. See, for example, [this topic](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?94144-Webflow-or-MVC&p=315533#post315533)
Consider using spring mvc instead, it has [much](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/) [more](http://hillert.blogspot.com/2011/01/rest-with-spring-contentnegotiatingview.html) opportunities for building restful applications